Parametrization of Spontaneous Symmetry Breaking
I am currently studying the spontaneous symmetry breaking part in Schwartz's Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model. I am solving the Problem 28.1.
In the main text, Schwartz presents the example of a linear sigma model with a single complex scalar. The Lagrangian is
$$ \mathcal L = (\partial_\mu \phi^*)(\partial^\mu \phi) + m^2 \phi \phi^* - \frac\lambda 4 \phi^2 \phi^{*2}\tag{28.10}$$
Schwartz used the parametrization of $\phi(x)$ given as
$$ \phi(x) = \left(\sqrt{\frac{2m^2}{\lambda}} + \frac1{\sqrt2} \sigma(x) \right)e^{i\frac{\pi(x)}{F_\pi}},\tag{28.11}$$
and it results in
$$
\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} (\partial_\mu \sigma)^2 + \left( \sqrt{\frac{2m^2}{\lambda}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sigma(x) \right)^2 \frac{1}{F_\pi^2} (\partial_\mu \pi)^2 \\
- \left( - \frac{m^4}{\lambda} + m^2 \sigma^2 + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\lambda} m \sigma^3 + \frac{1}{16} \lambda \sigma^4 \right) .\tag{28.12}
$$
Problem 28.1 asks to use the parametrization given as
$$
 \phi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2m^2}{\lambda}} + \tilde \phi(x)\tag{28.11'}
$$
and diagonalize the mass matrix.
My calculation gives
$$
\mathcal L = \frac12 (\partial_\mu \tilde\sigma)(\partial^\mu \tilde\sigma) + \frac12 (\partial_\mu \tilde\pi )(\partial^\mu \tilde\pi) - m^2 \tilde\sigma^2 - \frac12  \sqrt{\lambda} m  \tilde\sigma  (\tilde\sigma^2 + \tilde\pi^2 ) - \frac{\lambda}{16} [\tilde\sigma^2 + \tilde\pi^2 ]^2 .
$$
This parametrization also indicates the massless particle $\tilde\pi$ and the same form of self-interaction of $\tilde\sigma$ but the interaction between $\tilde\sigma$ and $\tilde\pi$ is different from Eq. (28.12). The Problem says that this parametrization results in the expansion in Eq. (28.12) but I get a different result.
What I want to ask is as follows.

Should these two parametrizations give the same result?
If not, is it okay for the interaction to depend on parametrization?


You are misreading your problem. In the paragraph below (28.12), Matt explains the form you should obtain in the alternate parameterization of problem (28.1), and why and how you would find the same answer for the masses in (28.3). Your calculation is incomprehensible: you should not have σ in it. Explain what you did first.

Are you assuming something like $\tilde \phi=\sigma+i\pi$??

Schwartz asked to diagonalize the mass matrix. By letting $\tilde \psi = v+ (1/\sqrt{2}) [\sigma + i \pi]$, mass terms are diagonalized and the above result comes out.

But…$\tilde φ$ already has v taken out!. And it’s real and imaginary parts should not have the old names!

Sorry, $\tilde \phi = (1/\sqrt2) [\sigma + i \pi]$ is correct.

But this is an unsound assumption. Your text never suggested it. It suggested arbitrary real and imaginary parts, which need not be the same as in the polar parameterization you are comparing to. You do understand that physical amplitudes (and their poles!) do not, cannot , depend on the particular field parameterization in QFT? (Weinberg's text details that.)

You misread your text:

would lead back to our linear sigma model

definitely does not mean it would lead to (28.12) with the  scalar fields $\tilde \sigma$ and $\tilde \pi$ (representing the real and imaginary parts of $\tilde \phi=(\tilde\sigma+ i \tilde\pi)/\sqrt 2$) identified with the $\sigma$ and $\pi$ of the polar parameterization (28.1)! That's the point of the reparameterization: you've transitioned from polar to Cartesian coordinates,
so your lagrangian looks different in terms of the new, tilded, Cartesian ones! It should not look the same. The interaction between these new degrees of freedom would of course look different, so "yes" to your 2. without its false premise!
But, as always, coordinates (QFT field parameterizations) should not really matter, and the amplitude pole structure described by your lagrangian and (28.12) should be the same! A resounding "yes" to your 1, where result does not mean lagrangian, but physics, instead. Your text is helping you appreciate that the different variables $\pi$ and $\tilde \pi$ have zero mass; and $\sigma$ and $\tilde \sigma$ have mass $\sqrt{2} m$, even though their mutual interactions are/appear different in detail.
You might solve for $\tilde\sigma, ~~\tilde\pi$ in terms of $\sigma, ~~\pi$ and track down the poles. Note the potential cannot depend on Goldstone bosons (such as $\pi$), but does seem to depend on $\tilde \pi$! Conversely, it is cleaned up in the polar parameterization (28.11).
This is probably best described in Weinberg's textbook, since he was fascinated by it in his work in the late 60s.

At the high-school-geeky algebraic level, for plain variables, you are meant to "see" and internalize the formal coincidence of the quadratic terms of all variables in $V=(\lambda/4)(z\bar z-v^2)^2$ for $z=(r+v)e^{i\theta}=v+x+iy$, so that $V= \lambda v^2r^2+...=\lambda v^2x^2+...$, ignoring the elided differing interaction terms, which is not a coincidence. There must be a pompous  algebraic term for it, which I don't know. In any case, the sombrero potential  you are examining has its bottom at zero (here) and the respective curvatures 0 and $2v^2$ there.

Side comment: while it is indeed true at mean-field that both amplitude ($\sigma$)  and longitudinal ($\tilde \sigma$) modes have the same mass, this is not correct beyond mean-field (in the ordered phase, with finite vev). The amplitude mode is indeed massive, but the longitudinal one is not, due to its strong coupling with the Goldstone modes.
